# Repeat a loop for another vector

Tags: loops

At first, i have a vector m1 of 100 values. Next, when the sum of the following function  `P(x+1)=P(x)(lambda/(x+1))^nu` or the cdf of the function exceeds the first value of m1 then it should give me that x value. Again, this loop should run for second value of m1 and so on so forth. Ultimately it should give me a 100 numbers. But the loop stops after the first loop. I tried with the following code,

```
critval=m1 
y=rep(NA,100) 
acumulated.distrib= function(sample,lambda,nu){ 
    p0=c0=0.017533668 
    for(i in 1:length(sample)){
        p <- p0*(lambda/(sample[i]+1)^nu) 
        c<- p+c0 
        c0=c 
        p0=p 
        for( t in 1:length(m1)){ 
            critval[t]=m1[t] 
            if (c > critval[t]){ 
                break 
            } 
        }  
    }  
    y[t]=sample[i] 
    print(sample[i]) 
} 
sample = seq(0,100,by=1) 
acumulated.distrib(sample,3,0.7)
```

It will be very helpful for, if anyone can give me some idea or suggestion regarding this problem.

Comment: I dont know what language it is, but probably in this one the "break" statement does not break only the inner cycle, but all cycles it is in?

Comment: You may want to tag your question with a relevant language. [R] perhaps?

Comment: Yes it is R language and thank you for your replay.